# Does using NOLOGGING in Oracle break ACID? specifically during poweroutage

Tags: oracle, acid

When using NOLOGGING in Oracle, say for inserting new records. Will my database be able to gracefully recover from a power outage? if it randomly went down during the insert.

Am I correct in stating that the the UNDO logs will be used for such recoveries ... as opposed to REDO log usage which be be used for recovery if the main datafiles were physically corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me, you're muddling some concepts together here.

First, let's talk about instance recovery.  Instance recovery is what happens following a database crash, whether it is killed, server goes down, etc.  On instance startup, Oracle will read data from the redo logs and roll forward, writing all pending changes to the datafiles.  Next, it will read undo, determine which transactions were not committed, and use the data in undo to rollback any changes that had not committed up to the time of the crash.  In this way, Oracle guarantees to have recovered up to the last committed transaction.

Now, as to direct loads and NOLOGGING.  It's important to note that NOLOGGING is *only* valid for direct loads.  This means that updates and deletes are *never* NOLOGGING, and that INSERT is only nologging if you specify the APPEND hint.

It's important to understand that when you do a direct load, you are literally "directly loading" data into the datafiles.  So, no need to worry about issues around instance recovery, etc.  When you do a NOLOGGING direct load, data is still written directly to the datafiles.

It goes something like this.  You do a direct load (for now, let set aside the issue of NOLOGGING), and data is loaded directly into the datafiles.  The way that happens, is that Oracle will allocate storage from above the high water mark (HWM), and format and load those brand new blocks directly.  When that block allocation is made, those data dictionary updates that describe the space allocation are written to and protected by redo.  Then when your transaction commits, the changes become permanent.

Now, in the event of an instance crash, either the transaction was committed (in which case the data is in the datafiles and the data dictionary reflects those new extents have been allocated), or it was not committed, and the table looks exactly like it did before the direct load began.  So, again, data up to and including the last committed transaction is recovered.

Now, NOLOGGING.  Whether a direct load is logged or not, is irrelevant for the purposes of instance recovery.  It will *only* come into play in the event of media failure and media recovery.

If you have a media failure, you'll need to recover from backup.  So, you'll restore the corrupted datafile and then apply redo, from archived redo logs, to "play back" the transactions that occurred from the time of the backup to the current point in time.  As long as all the changes were logged, this is not a problem, as all the data is there in the redo logs.  However, what will happen in the event of a media failure subsequent to a NOLOGGING direct load?

Well, when the redo is applied to your segments that were loaded with NOLOGGING, the required data is *not* in the redo.  So, those data dictionary transactions that I mentioned that created the new extents where data was loaded, those are in the redo, but nothing to populate those blocks.  So, the extents are allocated to the segment, but then are also marked as invalid.  So, if/when you attempt to select from the table, and hit those invalid blocks, you'll get ORA-26040 "data was loaded using the NOLOGGING option".  This is Oracle letting you know you have a data corruption caused by recovery through a NOLOGGING operation.

So, what to do?  Well, first off, any time you load data with NOLOGGING, make sure you can re-run the load, if necessary.  So, if you do suffer an instance failure during the load, you can restart the load, or if your suffer a media failure between the time of the NOLOGGING load and the next backup, you can re-run the load.

Note that, in the event of a NOLOGGING direct load, you're only exposed to data loss until your next backup of the datafiles/tablespaces containing the segments that had the direct load.  Once it's protected by backup, you're safe.

Hope this helps clarify the ideas around direct loads, NOLOGGING, instance recovery, and media recovery.

Answer (score 1):

IF you use NOLOGGING you don't care about the data. Nologging operations should be recoverable with other procedures than the regular databases recovery procedures. Many times the recovery will happen without problems. Problem is when you have a power failure on the storage. In that case you might end up corrupting the online redo - that was active - and because of that also have problems with corrupt undo segments.

So, specifically in your case: I would not bet on it.
Yes, much of the recovery would be done by reading undo, that might get stuck because of exactly the situation you described. That is one of the nastiest problems to recover.

Answer (score 0):

As to be 100% ACID compliant a DBMS needs to be serializable, this is very rare even amongst major vendors. To be serializable read, write and range locks need to be released at the end of a transaction. There are no read locks in Oracle so Oracle is not 100% ACID compliant.